# Solving Coupled Differential Equations with Second Derivative, but No First Derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this system of coupled differential equations?

$\frac{d^2\rho}{d\lambda^2}=\frac{5\rho}{(5\rho^2+4t^2)^2}$ $\frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2}=\frac{4t}{(5\rho^2+4t^2)^2}$

Is it something I could input in the Wolfram calculator?

Comment: Divide the two equations and then use separation of variables. Be careful that you don't treat the derivatives as fractions as they are second derivatives.

Comment: How does dividing second derivatives work, if I can't treat them as fractions?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you'll excuse me if I write $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ instead of $\rho(\lambda)$ and $t(\lambda)$.

The system has the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \ddot x \\ \ddot y \end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{(5x^2+4y^2)^2}
\begin{pmatrix} 5x \\ 4y \end{pmatrix}
=
- \begin{pmatrix} \partial V/\partial x \\ \partial V/\partial y \end{pmatrix}
,
$$
where
$$
V(x,y) = -\frac{1/2}{5x^2+4y^2}
.
$$
This means that the total energy (kinetic + potential) $E = \frac12 (\dot x^2 + \dot y^2) + V(x,y)$ is a constant of motion.

Moreover, in polar coordinates the potential $V$ takes the form
$$
V = - \frac{1/2}{r^2 (4+\cos^2 \phi)}
,
$$
which matches the general form for potentials that are *separable* in polar coordinates,
$$
V = f(r) + \frac{1}{r^2} \cdot g(\phi)
,
$$
with $f(r)=0$ and $g(\phi) = -\dfrac{1/2}{4+\cos^2 \phi}$.

What this means is that you can apply the *Hamilton–Jacobi method* in polar coordinates, which in principle allows you to integrate the equations explicitly (although in practice it can get a bit messy). Unfortunately this method is quite complicated, so I won't try to describe it here; see some textbook in classical mechanics, such as [Landau & Lifshitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_of_Theoretical_Physics) (Vol. 1, §48).

Comment: Which edition? What is the symbol you wrote behind the 48?

Comment: The one I have is the third edition. And “§” is a [section sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign).

Comment: Okay, thank you. What do I put in for the $S_0$, $S_1$, and $S_2$ in this case?

Comment: You seek an additively separated solution to the Hamilton–Jacobi equation: $S_0(r,\phi) = S_1(r) + S_2(\phi)$.

Comment: $S_0$ is $V(x,y)$ in your case?

Comment: No, $S_0$ is the sought solution to the HJ equation $H(r, \phi, \partial S_0 / \partial_r,\partial S_0 / \partial \phi) = E$, where $H(r, \phi, p_r, p_\phi) = \frac12 (p_r^2 + \tfrac{1}{r^2} p_\phi^2) + V(r,\phi)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142324/discussion-between-user345249-and-hans-lundmark).

Comment: Is this the correct HJ equation? $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial S_0}{\partial r})^2+f(r)+\frac{1}{2r^2}[(\frac{\partial S_0}{\partial\phi})^2+2b(\phi)]=E$

Comment: Yes, and when $S_0 = S_1(r)+S_2(\phi)$, it separates into two equations, one for $S_1$ and one for $S_2$.

Comment: The final result should come out just in terms of $r$, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. The quantities that you want to find are $r(t)$ and $\phi(t)$, which will give you the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ that you seek.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d^2\rho}{d\lambda^2}=\frac{5\rho}{(5\rho^2+4t^2)^2},\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2}=\frac{4t}{(5\rho^2+4t^2)^2}.\tag{2}$$
$$2\rho' \frac{d^2\rho}{d\lambda^2}=\frac{10\rho \rho '}{(5\rho^2+4t^2)^2},\tag{1}$$
$$2t'\frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2}=\frac{8t't}{(5\rho^2+4t^2)^2}.\tag{2}$$
Add both DE's and integrate:
$$2t'\frac{d^2t}{d\lambda^2}+2\rho' \frac{d^2\rho}{d\lambda^2}=\frac{8t't+10 \rho \rho'}{(5\rho^2+4t^2)^2}$$

$$t'^2+\rho'^2 =-\frac{1}{5\rho^2+4t^2}+C_1$$
$$t'^2+\rho'^2 =-\rho\rho''-tt''+C_1$$
$$(t't)'+(\rho \rho ')' =C_1$$
Integrate again:
$$t't+\rho \rho ' =C_1\lambda +C_2$$
Integrate again:
$$t^2+\rho ^2 =C_1\lambda^2 +2C_2\lambda+C_3$$
$$t^2+\rho ^2 =C_1\lambda^2 +C\lambda+C_3$$
You can use this result to eliminate $t$ or $\rho$ in the original DE. Unfortunately the DE won't be linear and therefore it's hard to solve.

Comment: Thank you! It will be hard to solve. Should I expect to be able to get exact answers for $t$ and $\rho$ in terms of $\lambda$?

Comment: You're welcome. I didnt do the calculations but as it looks seems hard to find an exact solution for either $\rho$ or $t$ @user345249